# Google Chrome not using local cache

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-cache

I've been using Google Chrome as a substitute for Firefox not being able to handle having lots of tabs open at the same time.

Unfortunately, it looks like Chrome is having the same problem.  Freakin useless.

I had to end Chrome as my whole system had slowed to a crawl.  When I restarted it, I opted to restore the tabs that were last open.  At this stage, every one of the 20+ tabs srated downloading the pages they had previously had open.

My question is: why can't they open a locally stored/saved copy of the web page from cache?  Does Google Chrome store pages in a cache?

Also: after most of the pages had completed their downloading, I clicked on each tab to view the page.  Half of them only display a white page, and I have to reload the page manually.  What is causing this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you scanned for malware?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: why can't they open a locally stored/saved copy of the web page from cache? Does Google Chrome store pages in a cache?

Most likely Chrome is using the cache, for content that has not expired (static content like images). The actual websites (the HTML) are probably served with a very short expiry time, so that when you visit them again you will see new content.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent short expiry times being honoured by the browser?  Content might change 4 times a year, so why bother consuming the extra bandwidth to reload pages that haven't changed?

Comment: @Steve - It's a bad idea. If you *really* want to do it, you will probably need to put a proxy in front of your browsers. `squid` allows you to enforce a minimum expiry - http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/refresh_pattern/ - but make sure you read what it says: *VIOLATES the HTTP standard.  Enabling this feature make you liable for problems which it causes.*

Answer (score 0):

What're you system specs ? Chrome handles multiple-tabs effortlessly, if you have sufficient memory.

If you see a white page then it (generally) means Chrome has run of memory and has moved the page contents to pagefile. Depending on your hard drive speed and number of running processes it might take some time for CHrome to fetch from Hard drive and put it back in RAM.

As @Moab mentions - scan for malware using Malwarebytes Anti-malware. Malware might be consuming all your available memory.

Comment: 1.80GHz Pentium M, 1024MB RAM.  I have scanned using MAM, and found no bugs.

Comment: Chrome dogs when first coming up, since, *if allowed*, it will consume all the CPU resources (600% cpu-core usage on my system) on your system to open all your extensions and tabs in parallel.  On starting, for  10-15 seconds, my mouse gets jerky and interactive responsiveness drops to zilch.  This is on a 3.4GHz hexacore Xeon, 96GB of memory (with no paging going on since the system isn't even close to using 96G) running on a 4-SSD RAID0.   I found that limiting it (w/affinity) to 3-4 cores substantially helps the problem.